# Prove that there is no $c\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $B^\star B=cI_3.$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $B\in \mathbb{C}^{3\times 3}$ with characteristic polynomial $-(x-1)^2(x-2).$ Prove that there is no $c\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $B^\star B=cI_3.$

**Attempt.** I noted that $B^\star B$ is Hermitian and therefore 
has only real eigenvalues (but this can not exclude the case $c\in \mathbb{R}$). On the other hand the eigenvalues of $B^\star$ are the same as those of $B$, i.e. $1$ and $2$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the hint by @user1551, let $B^\star B=cI_3$ for some complex $c$. Let $v_1,~v_2\neq 0$ be eigenvectors of $B$, corresponding to $1,~2,$ respectively. Then

$$\|v_1\|^2=<v_1,v_1>=<Bv_1, B v_1>=<v_1,B^\star B v_1>=<v_1,cI_3 v_1>=\bar{c}\|v_1\|^2$$

so $c=1$. From $Bv_2=2v_2$, we get $c=4$, contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint.* What properties do the eigenvalues of (the scalar multiple of) a unitary matrix enjoy?

Comment: Following your hint, i am wondering if $(a B)^\star (a B)=I_3$ for some $a\in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @NikolaosSkout Consider $v^\ast B^\ast Bv$ for any vector $v$.

Comment: Let $v_1,~v_2$ eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues $1,~2$, respectively, so $Bv_1=v_1,~Bv_2=2v_2$ and by considering that you suggested we get $c=1,~c=4,$ contradiction. Thank you!